# kernel 5.10.119 caused the values of /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail and poolsize to be 256

Tags: linux-kernel, proc, random, sysctl

After update to kernel 5.10.119, `/proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail` became stuck to 256 and does not change when moving the mouse. It used to be greater than 3000.

```
# cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail  
256
```

Also, `/proc/sys/kernel/random/poolsize` went down to 256. It used to be 4096.

Is this a bug? Can you trust the new random number generator of this kernel with only 256 available entropy?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

With no intention to compete with Marcus' complete answer. Just to explain what happened and justify that what you are noticing is not a bug.

Default poolsize is hardcoded in `drivers/char/random.c` but something actually changed in 5.10.119 :

**Up to 5.10.118** :

```
#define INPUT_POOL_SHIFT    12
#define INPUT_POOL_WORDS    (1 << (INPUT_POOL_SHIFT-5))
...
static int sysctl_poolsize = INPUT_POOL_WORDS * 32;
```

**(2^(12-5))x32=4096**

**Under 5.10.119**, poolsize appears computed differently :

```
POOL_BITS = BLAKE2S_HASH_SIZE * 8
...
static int sysctl_poolsize = POOL_BITS;
```

having  BLAKE2S_HASH_SIZE = 32 as defined in `include/crypto/blake2s.h`

**8x32=256** what you are noticing is not a bug… its : a feature !

BTW, it's just a default value, feel free to change it if you know it does not fit your needs.

---

Note : This change, which concerns mainline since 5.17-rc1 was backported to 5.10 from 119 but also to the more recent LTS : 5.15 from 44. 5.4 does not seem concerned (yet ?) and of course, 5.16 will never be.

---

As opportunely suggested by @TooTea in the comments, the reasons for the move can be read as part of [the initial commit](https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/20220527084855.501642285@linuxfoundation.org/), in short :

- increased security (if the state of the pool leaks, its contents could be controlled and entirely zeroed out.)
- better performances (up to 225% on hight end cpu)

This being achieved by replacing the 4096 LFSR by a direct call to the BLAKE2s.

> BLAKE2s outputs 256 bits, which should give us an appropriate amount
> of min-entropy accumulation, and a wide enough margin of collision
> resistance against active attacks.

Comment: very nice! +1 for actually (git?) diffing the versions! Or are you involved with the subsystem?

Comment: Thanks @MarcusMüller. In fact I am only carefully following on LKML what G-KH backports since some patches sometimes happen to break the build of my heavily patched kernel. ;-)

Comment: This explains the change in the poolsize value but I want to understand what the reason behind the change.

Comment: The other problem is entropy_avail is not responding to mouse movements. What happened to "entropy harvesting" from computer hardware?
I tried to search for materials about the rational of the change. I will appreciate if anyone can give some pointers.

Comment: @user528206 : regarding your last question, you mention in the OP having entropy_avail = 256 and poolsize = 256. Why would you want any event to increase the amount of available entropy ?

Comment: The reasons for the switch from the old "big entropy pool" approach to BLAKE2s are outlined in the original commit: https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/20220527084855.501642285@linuxfoundation.org/

Answer (score 11):

yes we can.

You could also before, when the same value would have been displayed – "entropy" is just a wild guess how much random sources for modifying the state of a pseudo-random number generator is available. Even if there was *no* new entropy, that generator would still be *trustworthy* – unless someone figured out the state (which *should* be impossible).

So, even for things like private key generation, *there is no security difference between using /dev/urandom (which uses the PRNG even if it can't modify its state from external entropy source) and using /dev/random (which blocks if there's nothing to modify the state)*, **unless** you assume an attacker might have known the state of the kernel-internal PRNG, through some fantastic measure (or because you're early booting a linux on a very limited device, without a source of entropy, and the state is deterministic, but then you simply have 0 entropy. Once you had a couple hundred bits of entropy, ever, any cryptographically secure PRNG says that *nobody* that gets data from the random generator can successfully guess its internal state).

The only difference is really that the already cryptographically secure PRNG is not being re-seeded if there's zero entropy. Having 3000 or 256 entropy "in store" doesn't matter at all. Only thing that makes a difference is whether you *can* reseed or not. (and as said, even that doesn't really matter unless you do something that I wouldn't cover as "cryptographically usual": How often do you really need to create a one-time-pad that no attacker with full knowledge of your computer's state at *one* point in time prior to generation can't crack? Because "attacker omniscient enough to infer your cryptographically PRNG's state at some time" is what you're protecting against, not "NSA trying to crack RSA" or something.)

Quite honestly,

> Is this a bug? Can you trust the new random number generator of this kernel with only 256 available entropy?

You need to assume your kernel doesn't introduce weakening of security measures. Otherwise the theoretical entropy in your source of randomness is not your problem, but that the kernel intentionally makes that deterministic in some way, without telling you :)

If you don't trust your kernel to not have security regressions, you've lost already, because you cannot trust your computer to deliver the numbers you think it should. Sooooo... yes, you can, or you needed to start building your own operating system a long time ago, not only with this update that changed the entropy shown.

**TL;DR:** As long as your computer doesn't suffer from *not enough entropy **ever**,* you're generating secure numbers. Even just 256 entropy once before starting to get random numbers, and then 0 for the rest of the lifetime of your system would be OK! Having 256 at any time is way more than ever necessary.

Comment: The problem is this sysctrl was used to monitor if a instance has a valid random generator. Especially in cloud images this was regularly not the case. Now with fixed 256 available it cant be monitored anymore. (The jury is still out on this one: do we need the monitor anymore?:)

Comment: @eckes Is it really fixed though? I would imagine that the value does not reach 256 at early boot, as the manual for getrandom alludes to. It's just that entropy is not "spent" (unless the pool is reset to zero size in case of compromise), so once it reaches 256 it stays there.