# How Does Linux Generate Random Numbers on Startup

Tags: boot, security, random

I am currently taking an OS class using XINU, where I am able to control every process running on the OS, and because of this, I can completely predict the output of its random number generator. [Here](https://github.com/xinu-os/xinu/blob/master/lib/libxc/rand.c) is the code.

It's clear to me, even this simple approach, when used on a desktop OS, would be able to create truly random numbers because there's so many processes behaving differently based on the user, location, or time. However, what about on startup, before there's any user input?

Linux's cryptographic random number generator is much more complex, but it still seems to rely on user input. OpenSSH runs on startup in a lot of Linux systems. I'm sure there's a lot companies that run configurations pretty close to stock, and if you can simulate the same hardware, software, and set the same time and location as the server you're attacking, couldn't you exploit that?

There's also premade deployments on many hosting services where devs can upload their code (dockerfile, ruby on rails project, etc), and the server will just set it up. Those servers have premade software, known hardware, location, and time. I'm assuming they have hardware randomness in the real-world, but what if they didn't?

Comment: Linux prior to or post 5.17-rc1 ? ( https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/704737/kernel-5-10-119-caused-the-values-of-proc-sys-kernel-random-entropy-avail-and-p/704743#704743 )

Comment: @MC68020 either one, or both. I'm more interested in high level approaches than a concrete code example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lack of entropy has been a problem, especially for older operating
systems where there was no random device or other such API available, or
for cloud or cloned operating systems that might all have more or less
exactly the same seed. Also, people keep doing silly things (e.g.
CVE-2020-27020) despite the availability of entropy sources.

One solution is to read from various random number sources at startup,
e.g. the RDRAND feature of some chips, and hopefully from multiple such
sources in the event that any one source is broken or compromised. This
may delay startup until "enough" entropy is gained. You can probably
find how various open source OS do this at startup by digging through
their source.

Another solution is to seed the system or virtual host with some amount
of pre-generated random data, perhaps generated by an installer or the
host operating system. This data is then used by the subsequent system
when it first starts up. This allows any number of otherwise identical
virtual systems to have a different set of entropy, provided the host
operating system generates suitable entropy for each host.

Comment: Makes sense, it looks like RDRAND was added to AMD chips after 2011 and intel before that, so pretty much every server out there should be using that. Does Virtualbox (and other vm software) create seeds from the host os to their child VMs by default? If so, I really doubt there's many computers that can be exploited with a vulnerability like this.