# Do we still need the haveged daemon with versions of linux after 5.10.119?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, random

Per [kernel 5.10.119 caused the values of /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail and poolsize to be 256](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/704737/kernel-5-10-119-caused-the-values-of-proc-sys-kernel-random-entropy-avail-and-p)

Linux locks the value of `/proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail` to 256.  Do we still need haveged?